# How to display images in search from a dnn module

Tags: search, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

In a DNN module which is `ISearchable`, is it possible to return an image with the search result?

The class `SearchItemInfo` has an `int Image` parameter but seemingly it is not described anywhere how to use it.

```cs
public SearchItemInfoCollection GetSearchItems(ModuleInfo ModInfo)
{
    var SearchItemCollection = new SearchItemInfoCollection();
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var controller = new ProductSetController();
        foreach (var product in controller.GetProductSets())
        {
            var SearchItem =
                new SearchItemInfo(product.Name, product.Summary, 0,
                        DateTime.Now, ModInfo.ModuleID, product.Code,
                        product.Description, "pid=" + product.Id.ToString(), 0);
            SearchItemCollection.Add(SearchItem);
        }
    }
    return SearchItemCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchItemInfo seems to have an ImageField property but it's not being used at the moment in the search results module of DotNetNuke. Please find below a link to the SearchResult.ascx user control of DotNetNuke.

[SearchResults User Control Source](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71579#1229846)